# PL/SQL wrapper for c# .net example

Tags: oracle11g

I have a c# dll and I have imported it into oracle database.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE LIBRARY Test_dll AS '$ORACLE_HOME\
bin\clr\Test_dll;
GRANT EXECUTE ON Test_dll TO TEST;
```

How to create a function for each method?

This is objective C example.

```
PROCEDURE plsToC_InBodyOld_proc (x BINARY_INTEGER, y VARCHAR2, z DATE) 
AS EXTERNAL
  LANGUAGE C
  NAME "C_InBodyOld"
  LIBRARY SomeLib
  WITH CONTEXT
  PARAMETERS(CONTEXT, x INT, y STRING, z OCIDATE);
```

How is it look like for C# .net?

Comment: Do you want to use C# to write your own stored procedures?

Comment: hi @zaratustra, that is one of the plan too...But I don't know the how it looks like... What is the language when creating procedure? I can't find any related source online, the only one I found is through the Visual Studio but I failed to do that... The deploy function of Build is missing. I did install ODTwithODAC121012

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to write stored procedures using C#, you can use either PL/SQL, or Java, or C. As I am aware, you can call the classes and methods of your dll using C through either OCI or OCCI interfaces, check [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28395/ociadwin.htm) to find out more.

**UPDATE**

This is not true. As @Stephen Drew mentioned the in the comment bellow you can [use C#](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dotnet/williams-sps-089817.html) to write stored procedures

Comment: Not true, see here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dotnet/williams-sps-089817.html

Comment: Thank you, I haven't come across this feature yet.